# How do I update the latest version of parent pom?

Tags: java, maven, plugins, pom.xml

In maven we have a pom which is child to a parent.

Child's pom :

```
<parent>
        <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-pom</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.3</version>
</parent>
```

Now I have added the following code to the child's pom, which updates the parent pom to the latest :

```
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>update-parent-version</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>update-parent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

So when I build the child pom, if the latest available parent is 6.0.6, then it gets updated to 6.0.6. But for compilation it is still taking the 6.0.3 parent's pom which was present initially. It is just updating the parent's version to the latest in the pom. How do I make it to take the latest for compiling also?

Comment: Which commands do you use for compilation and for build?

Comment: execute `mvn versions:update-parent` first

Comment: @FranMontero But that is what the `<phase>generate-sources</phase>` declaration is for in my opinion.

Comment: For any goal it is too late to adjust the `pom.xml`. Maven first creates an immutable buildplan, then it'll execute all the required goals based on this plan.

Comment: btw, this is a recipe for disaster: what if the latest parent contains a bug which blocks you from building? If you want to prevent usage of certain parent, you should add rules to your repository manager to verify that. Reason 2: the result of building these sources will be different over a year. That's certainly not what you want.